# Auto login on Mac OS through a process running as a daemon

Tags: macos

I have a python script that is running as a daemon on Mac OS and keeps looking for a particular USB drive on system, if USB is ejected, the system is locked using the following command

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend`

Now after the screen is locked, the script is still running and still looking for the USB, is it possible to unlock the screen when the USB is inserted in the system without having the user to enter the password?